# Laravel 8 crud using ajax: Uncaught ReferenceError: data_id is not defined

Tags: ajax, laravel-8, crud, edit, uncaught-reference-error

So I'm trying CRUD using ajax. Adding is fine but the Edit is not because of this error

> Uncaught ReferenceError: data_id is not defined

Here is my trigger button:

```
@foreach($admin_quests as $quest)
//some codes
<button class="btn btn-success" type="button" id="editBtn" data_id="{{ $quest->id }}">Edit</button>
@endforeach
```

Here is the controller:

```
use Response;
//some codes

public function edit(AdminQuest $adminQuest)
    {
        return Response::json($adminQuest);
    }
```

Here is the script:

```
$('body').on('click','#editBtn', function(){
            $('#addUpdateModal').modal('show');
            $('#modalTitle').html("EDIT QUEST");

            console.log($(this).attr('data_id'));

//THIS IS WHERE THE PROBLEM STARTS
            //admin_quest/{admin_quest}/edit
            $.get("{{ route('admin_quest.index') }}" + '/' + data_id + '/edit', function(data){
                //some codes
        });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I forgot to put
`data_id = $(this).attr('data_id');` to define data_id.

Comment: Please consider marking your answer as the solution to your question.